# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: iphone, uitableview, gdb

what is meaning

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

so that i can solve my problem
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero based addressing.

If you only have one item in an NSArray, the first item in an array is at index 0, not index 1.

Answer (score 2):

It means you attempted to access the second item (at index 1) in an array containing only one item (index 0).